# Will this {POST.data} construct work in a Yii email?

Tags: php, yii, adobe

I'm considering converting a website from Adobe to Yii. In the Adobe code, I have an include page of variables that uses the form POST data like this:

```
$firstContact = "This is an email I sent to {POST.userFirstName}";
```

When I submit, the post data is picked up by the variable and is sent nicely.

But as I start to convert these pages to Yii, I'm wondering if that {POST.userFirstName}
is something that Yii will recognize as php and properly deploy that POST data in the email message.

Can someone kindly tell me where to look in the Yii documentation that will actually
answer this, or, if you already know that it does work, just tell me that, too?

Thanks

Comment: I doubt it, though you could build such a thing in php.  Or use one of the many template systems to something similar etc.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix 
Thanks, I'll hang out for a more definitive response.

Comment: Sorry I don't know what all Yii offers, but syntax like that is not php its a template system.  In php it would be like this " words {$_POST['userFirstName']}  more words " or " words ". $_POST['userFirstName'] ." more words "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax in php would be like this

```
$firstContact  = "words ".$_POST['userFirstName']." more words ";
```

Or

```
 $firstContact  = "words {$_POST['userFirstName']} more words ";
```

But I would personally include this

```
 $userFirstName =  isset($_POST['userFirstName']) ? $_POST['userFirstName'] : '';
 $firstContact  = "words $userFirstName more words ";
```

In the case of emails with post data injected into them I would very strongly recommend adding htmlentities

```
 $userFirstName =  isset($_POST['userFirstName']) ? htmlentities($_POST['userFirstName'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"); : '';
 $firstContact  = "words $userFirstName more words ";
```

But please note this will render html useless such as `<p>html<\p>` for example, so it largely depends on what you need and if you can 100% trust the content, who is sending the email and who it's being sent to.  The reason is that a user could add html containing Javascript code that could hijack user data sessions etc. all kinds of evil things that is best avoided.

There are several ways to put variables in strings  ( interpolation ), Yii may offer a way like that but it's not done in native php as such.  A lot of template systems use similar syntax to what you have, but I am not of fan of using just `POST`, I would need the `_` in front as in `{_POST.var}` but that is just me.

The `.` in php is the concatenation operator similar to the `+` in Javascript.  Many template systems use it as an access operator, which is what Javascript does, this is simular to the `->` in php or `[ ]` in the case of an array.  In general template designers will be more familiar with Javascript, which is why they use the `.` that way.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking to hear. I appreciate your help tonight.

Comment: sure I would suggest using  http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php around any $_POST data that gets injected into html though, as a security measure,  in this form `htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");`  using this will prevent users from injecting Javascript code into your emails.